# In iOS, how can I block until restful api token is obtained

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my app, most pages are backed up by restful api responses. And many pages requires authentication so api token is required before user enters such pages.

In AppDelegate.m's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method I kick off a `NSURLSessionDataTask` to obtain the api token. But this call is async and users could enter and act on pages before the token arrives.

I use storyboard so the application loads my initial pages automatically. How can I make sure the pages are loaded after the token arrives, so I do not have to check for token existence almost anywhere api is used.

Comment: You can show loader at initial or custom splash screen till you receive the Access token. Once you receive just dismiss the loader and load the page accordingly.

Comment: Centralize your calls, and when it fails because of token, renew it. Think now about UI/UX and how are apps tells the users that's it's loading (renewing/getting the token is part of the loading in my opinion).

Comment: @AbilashBalasubramanian Thanks for the suggestion. Since you answered as a comment, I marked the answer which is similar to yours.

Comment: @Larme I used swagger to automatically generate all apis so I do not know how to centralize the calls, probably I have to dig into the generated code and afnetworking. Currently I do prefetch of tokens periodically, say every 19 minutes if the token refresh rate is 20 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have activity indicator view on your home page in storyboard. 
Or add a new view controller with activity indicator before you launch homepage.
In your newViewController, in view did load method check to see if the token is obtained or not ?
Depending on it just call a method to show alert view to show failure message otherwise push to your homeViewController ?

Another way is using singleton.

Comment: Thanks. Accepted as answer. And just curious, how does the singleton method work?

Comment: I am glad, it worked for you. But using singleton you store token and use it in entire app. The very principle of singleton that it need to initialise once is what requires for application like you. 

I would make a class like launcher and initialise as a singleton. And inside it would store token in keychain and use in the app. And launcher class would be call only once in app cycle.

Hope it make some sense

Answer (score 0):

```
Follow in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear method.

NSLog(@"auth_token is:%@", auth_token);

if ([auth_token isEqualToString:@""] || [auth_token isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
     // Show alert or put NSLog (so that we can avoid app crashing)
    [self showAlert:nil Descriprtion:@"Your auth token is empty"];
}
else
{
  NSLog(@"do your next process");

}
```